# How to run video present on a sever in windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I want to know how to run video present on a sever in windows 8 app.

I am using media element and binding source with the specific url.But video it not playing well if the video is on the local machine it able to play.

thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the [Player Framework](http://playerframework.codeplex.com), it works well from my usages with remote videos.

Comment: it got error that unable to create instance of mmppf:MediaPlayer  please tell me where i am wrong i added the refrence too